# How to make base class's certain constructor be callable only by particular derived class(es)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, constructor

```
struct Base {
  Base (type1, type2, type3);
  Base (); // <--- should be invoked only by `Derived_2`
  virtual ~Base() = 0;  // an abstract class
};
```

Say for above `Base`, we have multiple derived classes: `Derived_1`, `Derived_2`, ..., `Derived_N`.

While constructing an object, all derived classes must invoke `Base(type1, type2, type3)` constructor, except `Derived_2`, which should use `Base()` (the default constructor) while constructing the object.

Is there a way (C++11 is ok) to have such rule? In other words if anyone other than `Derived_2` tries to use the default no argument constructor then compiler should give an error.

**Edit**: For those who are asking about the design problem, I agree with that. Here is my take on it.

- Actually ideally I don't want the default constructor at all. All
  must use the argumented constructor, which takes **runtime**
  parameters in form of `type1, type2, type3`.
- Now, I am seeing few classes in the inheritance hierarchy whose
  objects are going to be instantiated globally before `main()` gets
  executed. Naturally those are special cases and have to entertain
  them by introducing a default constructor
- However this treatment is only for 1 or max 2 classes. Rest all the
  classes must maintain the rule of invoking argumented constructor.

I hope this makes the idea clear.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @PeterWood, the problem description will be very large and out of scope for SO. As of now, I want to restrict any accidental use of empty constructor of `Base`

Comment: A base class that needs to know about its derived types is not a very good design. It might be worth trying to redesign this.

Comment: @iammilind, I find it difficult to believe that it's impossible for you to give us some idea of why you think this would be a good idea without going "out of scope," so to speak. Why would it be *required* for a particular derived class to use a constructor with less information than the default constructor?

Comment: If a derived class cannot use the public methods from its base class, it looks like you are breaking the "is-a" relationship. See Meyer's Effective C++, Item 32: "Public inheritance means is-a. Everything that applies to base classes must also apply to derived classes"

Comment: @KyleStrand, Julien, Peter, see the update.

Comment: Is not posssible to change gobal objects to pointers and dynamically allocate within `main()` and avoid the default constructor?

Comment: If it's not possible to use pointers as hmjd suggests (which I think would probably be the correct thing to do), how about making the default constructor private and passing `null` args where the arg can't be known yet?

Comment: @hmjd, actually I haven't considered that option for uniformity. However Julien-L's answer seems quite reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would introduce another level of derivation:

```
        Base
         ^
         |
   +-----+------+
   |            |
Derived2    BaseWithParams
              ^         ^
              |         |
           Derived1    DerivedN
```

In the base, you implement no state or a default state (seems to me it makes sense to have a default state, since this is why `Derived2` was supposed to do).

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};
struct Derived2 : public Base
{
    Derived2() {}          // Do default initialization
    virtual ~Derived2() {} // Implement destructor so it's not pure virtual anymore
};
struct BaseWithCtor : public Base
{
    BaseWithCtor(type1, type2, type3) {}
    // Do not implement destructor, leave the class abstract
};
```

Answer (score 7):

The only way I can think of is declaring your `Base`'s default constructor private and making `Derived_2` a friend of your `Base` class, so it can call its default contructor.

However, this style is horrible, since your `Base` class now has to know about one of its derived classes. And it is still possible for `Dervived_2` to call the constructor with 3 parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Make the default constructor private, and declare Derived_2 as a friend:

```
class Derived_2;

class Base { 
    Base();
public:
    Base(int, int, int);
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
    friend class Derived_2;
};

class Derived_1 : public Base { 
public:
    Derived_1() : Base(1, 2, 3) {}
};

class Derived_1a : public Base { 
public:
    Derived_1() {} // will fail: Base::Base() not accessible
};


class Derived_2 :public Base { 
public:
   ~Derived_2() {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing the derived classes, then in only the second derived class should you call the default base constructor in the rest you can call the parameterised constructor.

```
      class derived1{             
                     derived1(): base(type1, type2, type3){}

                     };

       class derived2{
                      derived2(): base(){}
                      };
        class derived3{             
                     derived3(): base(type1, type2, type3){}

                     };
       class derived4{             
                     derived4(): base(type1, type2, type3){}

                     };
```

`

and so on. For the rest of the classes. Also... this is oop, you make the classes so you decide the behaviour of the classes yourself.
Therefore you just make sure that the default constructor for base class isn't called anywhere in the derived classes explicitly.
Everytime you need to call a constructor, you call the parameterised one in the derived classes, since afterall, you cnotrol the working of the class.